# Initializing NSImage(s) as static objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns

I have a custom control in OSX with a drawing routine. Every instance of this control uses the same images.

I wonder if it's a good idea to instantiate these images as static objects available for all the instances created by the class.

In case that was a good idea, how can I implement the image loader in a cleaver way? 
I thought to add to my class something like

```
static NSImage *imageone; 
static NSImage *imagetwo;
static NSImage *imagethree;
```

But I'm not sure about the better way to initialize the images... maybe a singleton function like this?

```
    + (void)setupSharedImages {
       static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

       dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
          imageone = [NSimage imageNamed:@"...."];
          imagetwo = [NSimage imageNamed:@"...."];
          image three = [NSimage imageNamed:@"...."];
       });   
     }
```

Comment: why? `imageNamed:` already handle caching for your

Comment: I should call imageNamed at every drawing cycle. I though it was better to setup the image once.

Comment: I believe calling `imageNamed:` is not expansive and when the images are not used, the system will be able to free them on memory low warning. Also loading many images at single place may take long and increase loading time.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup you images in `+ (void)initialize` method. This method is called once when class is loaded and it also handles synchronization.

As an option, you may think of incapsulating images into "storage" singleton class.

```
@interface ImageStorage : NSObject
+ (ImageStorage *)sharedStorage;
- (NSImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key;
@end

@implementation ImageStorage {
    NSDictionary *_images;
}

+ (ImageStorage *)sharedStorage
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static ImageStorage *sharedStorage;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedStorage = [[ImageStorage alloc] init];
       _images = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image1, key1, image2, key2, nil] retain];
   });

   return sharedStorage;
}

- (NSImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return [_images objectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always lazy load them.

```
- (NSImage *)imageOne {
    static NSImage *imageone;
    if(imageone == nil)
        imageone = [NSImage imageNamed:@"..."];
    return imageone;
}
```

Edit:
Just wanted to clarify, do this for each image you need then in your draw method call

`[self imageOne]` etc...